# Errors in Xcode 5 "use of undeclared identifier"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

I have the following errors in my Xcode project that I can not figure out how to correct it. I tried to save and close Xcode and reopen the project but this is not working. I am getting following message:

use of undeclared identifier'gremoveads'  with the following code.

```
}
if (buttonIndex==2) {
    bool bPaymentInQueue = NO;
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in [SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue].transactions) {
        if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:gRemoveads]) {
            bPaymentInQueue = YES;
            NSLog(@"Payment already in queue!");
            break;
        }
```

I am also getting this error.  Use of undeclared identifier 'gunlimitedcoins' with the following code.

```
if (buttonIndex==0) {
    bool bPaymentInQueue = NO;
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in [SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue].transactions) {
        if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:gUnlimitedCoins]) {
            bPaymentInQueue = YES;
            NSLog(@"Payment already in queue!");
            break;
```

How do I fix these two undeclared identifier errors?

The full code showing these errors are in the gamestoreviewcontroller.m file

```
#import "GameStoreViewController.h"
#import "Reachability.h"
#import "SurfSlotMachineAppDelegate.h"

@implementation GameStoreViewController
@synthesize activityIndicatorView;
@synthesize lblLoading;
@synthesize lblProductTitle;
@synthesize txtProductDescription;
@synthesize txtGamecenterDescription;
@synthesize txtRestoreDescription;
@synthesize txtMoreGamesDescription;
@synthesize btnBuyProduct;
@synthesize btnGameCenter;
@synthesize btnRestore;
@synthesize btnReturn;
@synthesize btnMoreGame;
@synthesize activityIndicatorPurchasingView;
@synthesize lblPurchasing;
@synthesize unlockInfoImage;

/*
 // The designated initializer.  Override if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
 if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
 // Custom initialization
 }
 return self;
 }
 */

/*
 // Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 }
 */

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    //    SurfSlotMachineAppDelegate* del = (SurfSlotMachineAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    //    [del hideADS:YES];

    bErrorOnConnection = NO;
    self.lblProductTitle.hidden = YES;
    self.txtProductDescription.hidden = YES;
    self.txtGamecenterDescription.hidden = YES;
    self.txtRestoreDescription.hidden = YES;
    self.txtMoreGamesDescription.hidden = YES;
    self.btnBuyProduct.hidden = YES;
    self.btnRestore.hidden = YES;
    self.btnGameCenter.hidden = YES;
    self.btnMoreGame.hidden = YES;

    self.lblLoading.hidden = YES;
    self.activityIndicatorPurchasingView.hidden = YES;
    self.lblPurchasing.hidden = YES;
    self.unlockInfoImage.hidden = YES;

    // Check network reachability
    Reachability* reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.google.com"];
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
    if (internetStatus != ReachableViaWiFi && internetStatus != ReachableViaWWAN) {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Internet Connection"
                                                        message:@"You require an internet connection via WiFi or cellular network for connecting to online store"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        bErrorOnConnection = YES;
    }




    if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
    {
        [self requestProductData];

    } else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"In-App Purchases are disabled"
                                                        message:@"Please check your restrictions for In-App Purchases in Settings->General->Restrictions."
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        bErrorOnConnection = YES;
    }

    //timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(tick:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    //[timer retain];
}
- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    UIAlertView  *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"In-App Store unavailable" message:error.localizedDescription delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] autorelease];

    [alert show];
}
- (void)setMainGameParent:(id) parent {
    mainGameParent = parent;
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [timer invalidate];
    [timer release];
}

/*
 // Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
 // Return YES for supported orientations
 return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
 }
 */

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];

    self.activityIndicatorView = nil;
    self.lblLoading = nil;
    self.lblProductTitle = nil;
    self.txtProductDescription = nil;
    self.txtRestoreDescription = nil;
    self.txtGamecenterDescription = nil;
    self.txtMoreGamesDescription = nil;
    self.btnBuyProduct = nil;
    self.btnGameCenter = nil;
    self.btnRestore = nil;
    self.btnMoreGame = nil;
    self.btnBuyProduct = nil;
    self.unlockInfoImage = nil;

    mainGameParent = nil;

    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

- (IBAction) closePressed:(id) sender {
    [mainGameParent GameStoreClosed];
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}

- (IBAction) purchaseUnlock:(id) sender {

    UIActionSheet *Sheet=[[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"Option" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Super Coins",@"Unlock Payouts",@"RemoveAds", nil];
    [Sheet showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];

    //[self.view removeFromSuperview];
}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    if (buttonIndex==actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex) {

    }
    if (buttonIndex==0) {
        bool bPaymentInQueue = NO;
        for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in [SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue].transactions) {
            if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:gUnlimitedCoins]) {
                bPaymentInQueue = YES;
                NSLog(@"Payment already in queue!");
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!bPaymentInQueue) {
            NSLog(@"Adding new payment...");
            SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:gUnlimitedCoins];
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
        }
    }
    if (buttonIndex==1) {
        bool bPaymentInQueue = NO;
        for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in [SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue].transactions) {
            if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:kPayoutUnlockProduct]) {
                bPaymentInQueue = YES;
                NSLog(@"Payment already in queue!");
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!bPaymentInQueue) {
            NSLog(@"Adding new payment...");
            SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:kPayoutUnlockProduct];
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
        }
    }
    if (buttonIndex==2) {
        bool bPaymentInQueue = NO;
        for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in [SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue].transactions) {
            if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:gRemoveads]) {
                bPaymentInQueue = YES;
                NSLog(@"Payment already in queue!");
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!bPaymentInQueue) {
            NSLog(@"Adding new payment...");
            SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:gRemoveads];
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
        }
    }
}

- (IBAction) gameCenter:(id)sender {
    SurfSlotMachineAppDelegate* del = (SurfSlotMachineAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    RootViewController *rootViewController = del.viewController;
    [rootViewController showLeaderboard];
}

- (IBAction) restore:(id)sender {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}

- (IBAction) moreGames:(id)sender {
    SurfSlotMachineAppDelegate* del = (SurfSlotMachineAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    [del dispMoreApps];
}

- (void)requestProductData {

    lblLoading.hidden = NO;
    [activityIndicatorView startAnimating];

    SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:kPayoutUnlockProduct]];
    request.delegate = self;
    [request start];
}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
    NSArray *myProducts = response.products;
    NSLog(@"%@",myProducts);
    if ([myProducts count] > 0) {
        SKProduct *product = [myProducts objectAtIndex:0];

        NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [numberFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
        [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
        [numberFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];
        NSString *priceString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];

        NSLog(@"Title: %@", product.localizedTitle);
        NSLog(@"Desc: %@", product.localizedDescription);
        NSLog(@"Price: %@", priceString);

        self.lblProductTitle.text = product.localizedTitle;
        self.txtProductDescription.text = product.localizedDescription;
        [self.btnBuyProduct setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Choose your UPGRADE"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.btnGameCenter setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Leaderboard"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.btnRestore setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Restore"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.btnMoreGame setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"More Games"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        self.lblProductTitle.hidden = NO;
        self.txtProductDescription.hidden = NO;
        self.txtGamecenterDescription.hidden = NO;
        self.txtRestoreDescription.hidden = NO;
        self.txtMoreGamesDescription.hidden = NO;
        self.btnBuyProduct.hidden = NO;
        self.btnGameCenter.hidden = NO;
        self.btnRestore.hidden = NO;
        self.btnMoreGame.hidden = NO;
        self.unlockInfoImage.hidden = NO;

        [numberFormatter release];
    }

    lblLoading.hidden = YES;
    [activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];

    [request release];
}


- (void)tick:(id)sender {

    bool bPaymentInQueue = NO;
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in [SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue].transactions) {
        if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:kPayoutUnlockProduct]) {

            bPaymentInQueue = YES;
            break;
        }
    }


    if (bPaymentInQueue) {
        [self.activityIndicatorPurchasingView startAnimating];
        self.activityIndicatorPurchasingView.hidden = NO;
        self.lblPurchasing.hidden = NO;
        self.btnReturn.enabled = NO;
        self.btnBuyProduct.enabled = NO;
    } else {
        [self.activityIndicatorPurchasingView stopAnimating];
        self.activityIndicatorPurchasingView.hidden = YES;
        self.lblPurchasing.hidden = YES;
        self.btnReturn.enabled = YES;
        self.btnBuyProduct.enabled = YES;
    }

    NSUserDefaults *userDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([userDefault objectForKey:KEY_PAYOUTLOCKED] != nil && [userDefault boolForKey:KEY_PAYOUTLOCKED] == NO) {
        [mainGameParent GameStoreClosed];
        [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    }

    if (bErrorOnConnection) {
        [mainGameParent GameStoreClosed];
        [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: Isn't the error message pretty clear?

Comment: Either a learner or in New year mood to award points... :p

Comment: I am a beginner, and easy points for the one that can help me please!

Comment: @mmb316: *You* wrote the code, so you should know what `gRemoveads` and `gUnlimitedCoins` are. *We* can only guess.

Comment: I did not write the code unfortunately. I had a programmer that did a poor job and sent me something that does not work.

Comment: In the left-hand column, pick the "search" tab and search for each of your missing variables (individually).  See if there is any declaration anywhere.  This may give you some clues.  (Though it's really impossible for us to help you much more than that, without having access to the entire project.)

Comment: (I hope you haven't paid the guy yet.)

Comment: There is a good bet they are globals.

Answer (score 0):

You did not declared these:

```
gRemoveads
```

and

```
gUnlimitedCoins
```

The declarations are missing for these in the scope/block.

Comment: Show full code. As from where are you getting and putting the values in these two variables.

Comment: As from the code you dont have any `NSString *gRemoveads = ....;` or similar thing where you put any value on it. Either create variables locally or use a constant variables as you have `kPayoutUnlockProduct `

Comment: - (void) completeTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
 // Your application should implement these two methods.
    //[self recordTransaction: transaction];
    [self provideContent: transaction.payment.productIdentifier];

Comment: How and where do I write these two methods?

Comment: one such method is `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {`  and we cant tell what you want in the method :(  Its your requirement and logic that will be there in the methods.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the variable "gRemoveads" in the statement "transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:gRemoveads" has never been declared or set. From the computer's perspective, this variable doesn't exist. Do you know what this variable is or where it is supposed to be set?

Or are those supposed to be string literals? As in the exact text "gRemoveads". In that case, put it in quotes.

Comment: `From the computer's perspective`?? Shouldn't be it From the **compiler's** perspective?

Comment: No I am not sure where to declare these. How do I set them so they exist? In which part of Xcode should I be looking to add these?

Comment: Looking at it again, I believe those were meant to be string literals... put quotes around them, like this: if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:"gRemoveads"]) {

Comment: @DamienBlack: nice guess. If he wants a string constant, then better to use a variable or macro with const string, not directly putting it in code.